# How to properly set values based on slices in pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data:

```
university_towns[0:15]
```

I tried to make states **bold** in the code snippet but it doesn't work so I leave them in ** brackets for better visibility, original data doesn't have any ** brackets, there is no distinction between town names and state names.

```
    RegionName
    0        **Alabama**
    1         Auburn
    2       Florence
    3   Jacksonville
    4     Livingston
    5     Montevallo
    6           Troy
    7     Tuscaloosa
    8       Tuskegee
    9         **Alaska**
    10     Fairbanks
    11       **Arizona**
    12     Flagstaff
    13         Tempe
    14        Tucson
```

And so on, basically, there is a State Name, and then list of cities in this state. I want to make my data look like this:

```
      RegionName     State
1         Auburn   Alabama
2       Florence   Alabama
3   Jacksonville   Alabama
4     Livingston   Alabama
5     Montevallo   Alabama
6           Troy   Alabama
7     Tuscaloosa   Alabama
8       Tuskegee   Alabama
10     Fairbanks    Alaska
12     Flagstaff   Arizona
13         Tempe   Arizona
14        Tucson   Arizona
16   Arkadelphia  Arkansas
17        Conway  Arkansas
18  Fayetteville  Arkansas
```

I managed to solve it with this code:

```
    # getting the list of the states
    states = zillow_homes['State'].unique()
    # geting the indexes of the states in my data frame
    state_indexes = university_towns[university_towns['RegionName'].isin(states)].index
    university_towns['State'] = np.nan
    # operation

    for id in range(1, len(state_indexes-1)):
        start_id = state_indexes[id-1]+1
        end_id = state_indexes[id]
        university_towns['State'].loc[start_id:end_id-1] = university_towns['RegionName'].loc[start_id-1]
    # droping rows with no state(original state rows)
    university_towns.dropna(subset=['State'], inplace=True)
```

However I do get this warning message:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

Is there a proper way to achieve the same result? And also more efficient?

Comment: Can you please show what your dataset from where State comes looks like?

Comment: are the state names always begin and end with ** ?

Comment: Sorry the state names don't have the ** signs I tried to make them bold for better visibility but apparently it doesn't work in code snippets. I'm editing it out

Comment: @FaridJafri I pull the state list from my other data set that actually has them, It's this one: http://files.zillowstatic.com/research/public/City/City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

supposed you have a dataframe of state names (let's say `df_state`)

```
df_state

    State
0   Alabama
1   Alaska
2   Arizona
```

you can left join the `university_towns` dataframe with `df_state` with `indicator=True` parameter

```
df_result = university_towns.merge(df_state, how='left', left_on='RegionName', right_on='State', indicator=True)
df_result

RegionName          State        _merge
0   Alabama         Alabama      both
1   Auburn          NaN          left_only
2   Florence        NaN          left_only
3   Jacksonville    NaN          left_only
4   Livingston      NaN          left_only
5   Montevallo      NaN          left_only
6   Troy            NaN          left_only
7   Tuscaloosa      NaN          left_only
8   Tuskegee        NaN          left_only
9   Alaska          Alaska       both
10  Fairbanks       NaN          left_only
11  Arizona         Arizona      both
12  Flagstaff       NaN          left_only
13  Tempe           NaN          left_only
14  Tucson          NaN          left_only
```

the you can use `.fillna(method='ffill')` to fill NaN value with previous value, then just select the data that have `left_only` in the `_merge` column, then drop the `_merge` column

```
df_result = df_result.fillna(method='ffill').query('_merge == "left_only"').drop('_merge', 1)
df_result

RegionName        State
1   Auburn        Alabama
2   Florence      Alabama
3   Jacksonville  Alabama
4   Livingston    Alabama
5   Montevallo    Alabama
6   Troy          Alabama
7   Tuscaloosa    Alabama
8   Tuskegee      Alabama
10  Fairbanks     Alaska
12  Flagstaff     Arizona
13  Tempe         Arizona
14  Tucson        Arizona
```

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for!